# xCode 4.4 "Not Responding" Debug Output

Tags: xcode, ide

just updated to xCode 4.4, and the xCode process consistently hangs "Not Responding" when debugging an app either on the simulator or mobile device.

I have narrowed the issue to an async web request which outputs the received data transactions within the debug window. it's not excessive output, about 500k of xml data.

there also seems to be VERY poor performance with output on other http transactions which are substantially smaller in size.

i know it's not the app, since, i can run the application without any challenges natively on the simulator or iphone; however, once attached to the xcode ide the issues resume.

... is this a buffer sizing challenge within the xcode ide for debugging output?

thanks all,